# How to create a spark DataFrame from Nested JSON structure

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to load data from the ExactOnline API into a spark DataFrame. Data comes out of the API in a *very* ugly format. I have multiple lines of valid JSON objects in one JSON file. One line of JSON looks as follows:

```json
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "uri": "https://start.exactonline.nl/api_endpoint",
                    "type": "Exact.Web.Api.Models.Account",
                },
                "Accountant": null,
                "AccountManager": null,
                "AccountManagerFullName": null,
                "AccountManagerHID": null,
                ...
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "uri": "https://start.exactonline.nl/api_endpoint",
                    "type": "Exact.Web.Api.Models.Account",
                },
                "Accountant": null,
                "AccountManager": null,
                "AccountManagerFullName": null,
                "AccountManagerHID": null,
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I need is that the keys of the dictionary's in the results list become the dataframe columns, and the number of dictionary's in the results become my rows. In the example I provided above, that would result in a dataframe with the following columns:

```
__metadata|Accountant|AccountManager|AccountManagerFullName|AccountManagerHID
```

And two rows, one for each entry in the "results" list.

In Python on my local machine, I am easily able to achieve this by using the following code snippet:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

folder_path = "path_to_json_file"


def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]


with open(folder_path) as f:
    # Extract relevant data from each line in the JSON structure and create a nested list,
    # Where the "inner" lists are lists with dicts
    # (1 line of JSON in my file = 1 inner list, so if my JSON file has 6
    # lines the nested list will have 6 lists with a number of dictionaries)
    data = [json.loads(line)["d"]["results"] for line in f]
    # Flatten the nested lists into one giant list
    flat_data = flatten(data)

# Create a dataframe from that flat list.
df = pd.DataFrame(flat_data)
```

However, I'm using a Pyspark Notebook in Azure Synapse, and the JSON files reside in our Data Lake so I cannot use `with open` to open files. I am limited to using spark functions. I have tried to achieve what I described above using `spark.explode` and `spark.select`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf

df = spark.read.json(path=path_to_json_file_in_data_lake)
df_subset = df.select("d.results")
df_exploded = df_subset.withColumn("results", sf.explode(sf.col("results")))
```

df_exploded has the right number of *rows*, but not the proper columns. I think I'm searching in the right direction but cannot wrap my head around it. Some assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say **right number of rows, but not the proper columns**. What is the problem on the column? You have extra columns ? fewer ?

Comment: It simply gives me the right number of rows but only one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code, it is working fine. Just missing one last step :

```py
df_exploded = df_subset.withColumn("results", sf.explode(sf.col('results')))

df_exploded.select("results.*").show()

+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------+
|AccountManager|AccountManagerFullName|AccountManagerHID|Accountant|          __metadata|
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------+
|          null|                  null|             null|      null|[Exact.Web.Api.Mo...|
|          null|                  null|             null|      null|[Exact.Web.Api.Mo...|
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you explain to me why I need to first use df.select(d.results) before I can explode, and why do I need to select results.* afterwards?

Comment: In your question, your last step is the `explode`. From there, you end up with the content of the array which is a struct type. You need the `result.*` to transform the struc to a set of columns. That was the only step missing after what you did. It is exactly the same step as `df_subset = df.select('d.results')` except you use the `*` as a generic column selector.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely get what you're saying - I still need to use the step `df_subset = df.select("d.results")` before the explode step, otherwise I get an error.

Comment: I'm just saying that I took your code from its last line (starting with `df_exploded =`) and then I added just one missing line. Of course, you need all the previous line, they are good.

Answer (score 2):

you can directly read JSON files in spark with `spark.read.json()`, but use the `multiLine` option as a single JSON is spread across multiple lines. then use `inline` sql function to explode and create new columns using the struct fields inside the array.

```py
json_sdf = spark.read.option("multiLine", "true").json(
    "./drive/MyDrive/samplejsonsparkread.json"
)

# root
#  |-- d: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- results: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- AccountManager: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- AccountManagerFullName: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- AccountManagerHID: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- Accountant: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- __metadata: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
```

```py
# use `inline` sql function to explode and create new fields from array of structs
df.selectExpr("inline(d.results)").show(truncate=False)

# +--------------+----------------------+-----------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |AccountManager|AccountManagerFullName|AccountManagerHID|Accountant|__metadata                                                               |
# +--------------+----------------------+-----------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |null          |null                  |null             |null      |{Exact.Web.Api.Models.Account, https://start.exactonline.nl/api_endpoint}|
# |null          |null                  |null             |null      |{Exact.Web.Api.Models.Account, https://start.exactonline.nl/api_endpoint}|
# +--------------+----------------------+-----------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

# root
#  |-- AccountManager: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- AccountManagerFullName: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- AccountManagerHID: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- Accountant: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- __metadata: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any documentation related to inline? I cannot seem to find it but want to learn more about what it does.

Comment: @Psychotechnopath -- `inline` is a spark-sql function. see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline)